# The problem with selective "reading" of data from XML

Tags: c#, xml

I need to read an XML file that contains general order data, as well as detailed information about the products ordered. I place the general order data in the dataGridView. In the second DGV he would like to put data from the selected order, e.g. `<positionitem>, <materialcode>, <materialcatalognumber>, <materialdescription>, <quantity>, <unit>` for the tag `<DocId>` = 222.

I create code in Visual Studio Community 2017

Below the code reading the order data from the variable "pobraneDane" and XML data.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(pobraneDane);
XmlNodeList DocId = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DocId");
XmlNodeList DocNoExternal = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DocNoExternal");
XmlNodeList DocNo = doc.GetElementsByTagName("DocNo");            
for (int i = 0; i < doc.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(DocId[i].InnerXml, DocNoExternal[i].InnerXml, DocNo[i].InnerXml);
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <ZdDocListGetResponse xmlns="http://www.serwer.pl">
            <ArrayZdDocListGetResult>
            <Status>1</Status>
            <ZdDocListGetResult>
                <ZdListGetHeaderResult>
                    <DocId>222</DocId>
                    <DocNo>2019/a/008</DocNo>
                    <DateDoc>2019-01-10T00:00:00</DateDoc>
                    <DocStatus>W</DocStatus>
                    <DocAddressDelivery>Koluszki, ul Jasna 12 </DocAddressDelivery>
                    <DocWarehouse>abc</DocWarehouse>
                    <DateRealizationPlanned>2019-02-19T00:00:00</DateRealizationPlanned>
                    <ArrayZdListGetLinesResult>
                        <ZdListGetLinesResult>
                            <PositionItem>1</PositionItem>
                            <MaterialCode>23456</MaterialCode>
                            <MaterialCatalogNumber>10-20-30</MaterialCatalogNumber>
                            <MaterialDescription>Stolik nocny Prometeusz</MaterialDescription>
                            <Quantity>2.0000</Quantity>
                            <Unit>SZT</Unit>
                        </ZdListGetLinesResult>
                        <ZdListGetLinesResult>
                            <PositionItem>2</PositionItem>
                            <MaterialCode>386700</MaterialCode>
                            <MaterialCatalogNumber>10-20-40</MaterialCatalogNumber>
                            <MaterialDescription>Komoda Kasjopea</MaterialDescription>
                            <Quantity>1.0000</Quantity>
                            <Unit>SZT</Unit>
                        </ZdListGetLinesResult>
                    </ArrayZdListGetLinesResult>
                    <ArrayZdListGetNotesResult/>
                </ZdListGetHeaderResult>
                <ZdListGetHeaderResult>
                    <DocId>333</DocId>
                    <DocNo>2019/b/009</DocNo>
                    <DateDoc>2019-01-14T00:00:00</DateDoc>
                    <DocStatus>W</DocStatus>
                    <DocAddressDelivery>Pacanowo, kozia 2</DocAddressDelivery>
                    <DocWarehouse>def</DocWarehouse>
                    <DateRealizationPlanned>2019-02-27T00:00:00</DateRealizationPlanned>
                    <ArrayZdListGetLinesResult>
                        <ZdListGetLinesResult>
                            <PositionItem>1</PositionItem>
                            <MaterialCode>554433</MaterialCode>
                            <MaterialCatalogNumber>10-20-30</MaterialCatalogNumber>
                            <MaterialDescription>Stolik nocny Prometeusz </MaterialDescription>
                            <Quantity>1.0000</Quantity>
                            <Unit>SZT</Unit>
                        </ZdListGetLinesResult>
                        <ZdListGetLinesResult>
                            <PositionItem>2</PositionItem>
                            <MaterialCode>888999</MaterialCode>
                            <MaterialCatalogNumber>10-20-50</MaterialCatalogNumber>
                            <MaterialDescription>Szafa Viktoria </MaterialDescription>
                            <Quantity>1.0000</Quantity>
                            <Unit>SZT</Unit>
                        </ZdListGetLinesResult>
                    </ArrayZdListGetLinesResult>
                    <ArrayZdListGetNotesResult/>
                </ZdListGetHeaderResult>
            </ZdDocListGetResult>
        </ArrayZdDocListGetResult>
    </ZdDocListGetResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I would like to ask for an example of the code which I will extract the details of the selected order - the order number is: `<DocId>`
The order details are e.g. `<MaterialCode>`

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you switch to Linq-to-XML over the old DOM  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-vs-dom

Comment: You might want to consider [loading a DataSet from Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/loading-a-dataset-from-xml) which could spare you the boilerplate code to iterate Xml nodes and give you a DataTable (or View) you cab bind directly to your DataGridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication45
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ZdListGetHeaderResult").FirstOrDefault().GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<HeaderResult> results = root.Descendants(ns + "ZdListGetHeaderResult").Select(x => new HeaderResult()
            {
                DocId = (int)x.Element(ns + "DocId"),
                DocNo = (string)x.Element(ns + "DocNo"),
                DateDoc = (DateTime)x.Element(ns + "DateDoc"),
                DocStatus = (string)x.Element(ns + "DocStatus"),
                DocAddressDelivery = (string)x.Element(ns + "DocAddressDelivery"),
                DocWarehouse = (string)x.Element(ns + "DocWarehouse"),
                DateRealizationPlanned = (DateTime)x.Element(ns + "DateRealizationPlanned"),
                lines = x.Descendants(ns + "ZdListGetLinesResult").Select(y => new LinesResult()
                {
                    PositionItem = (int)y.Element(ns + "PositionItem"),
                    MaterialCode = (int)y.Element(ns + "MaterialCode"),
                    MaterialCatalogNumber = (string)y.Element(ns + "MaterialCatalogNumber"),
                    MaterialDescription = (string)y.Element(ns + "MaterialDescription"),
                    Quantity = (decimal)y.Element(ns + "Quantity"),
                    Unit = (string)y.Element(ns + "Unit"),
                }).ToList()

            }).ToList();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("DocId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DocINo", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DateDoc", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("DocStatus", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DocAddressDelivery", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DocWarehouse", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DateRealizationPlanned", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("PositionItem", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("MaterialCode", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("MaterialCatalogNumber", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("MaterialDescription", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(string));

            foreach (HeaderResult result in results)
            {
                foreach (LinesResult line in result.lines)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        result.DocId,
                        result.DocNo,
                        result.DateDoc,
                        result.DocStatus,
                        result.DocAddressDelivery,
                        result.DocWarehouse,
                        result.DateRealizationPlanned,
                        line.PositionItem,
                        line.MaterialCode,
                        line.MaterialCatalogNumber,
                        line.MaterialDescription,
                        line.Quantity,
                        line.Unit
                    });
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            DataTable dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("DocId") == 222).CopyToDataTable();
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
        }
    }
    public class HeaderResult
    {
        public int DocId { get; set; }
        public string DocNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateDoc { get; set; }
        public string DocStatus { get; set; }
        public string DocAddressDelivery { get; set; }
        public string DocWarehouse { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateRealizationPlanned { get; set; }
        public List<LinesResult> lines { get; set; }
    }
    public class LinesResult
    {
        public int PositionItem { get; set; }
        public int MaterialCode { get; set; }
        public string MaterialCatalogNumber { get; set; }
        public string MaterialDescription { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Unfortunately, I do not understand this code and I can not use it.

Comment: The code is using the Net Library XML Linq to read the file and put results into classes.

Comment: OK. I can put all headers in DGV

Comment: ```foreach (HeaderResult Order in results)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Order.DocId, Order.DocNo, Order.DateDoc, Order.DocStatus, Order.DocAddressDelivery, Order.DocWarehouse, Order.DateRealizationPlanned);
            }```

Comment: but how to choose all lines (PositionItem, MaterialCode etc.) for DocID = 222

Comment: It works very well. I am very grateful to you - I have a problem solved and will learn to use Linq.

Comment: I have a different, slightly similar problem.
I need to read XML and put data in DataGridView.
Unfortunately, the XML structure is quite different and I can't handle it. Can you help me again?

Comment: Post data and I will help.

Comment: I described my problem in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57861683/i-have-problem-with-read-xml-with-child-nodes-in-c-sharp